# html background-image disappears

Tags: html, background-image

the background image just flickers for a sec and then goes away. This has popped up recently. [Link](http://liep2vsk.edu.lv/header.php).
Tags used:

```html
background-image: url(images/background/DSCN7325_opacity_23_rays.jpg);
 background-repeat: repeat-y;
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `background-image: url();` style of `body` from your css file (center_all.css)

Comment: Thanks. This solved it. Though I did it the other way around. Removed the code from an html page and added it to css file since it is linked to a wider scope of pages.

Comment: @user72160 You're welcome. yes, that is an another way. if you think fit, accept this answer.